# Best way to implement Categories and Subcategories with flexible depth in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a Category and Subcategory models in my project. I would like to have many sub-levels in a flexible way. I thought making a self referential "parent" foreign key but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Cat1
    Sub1
        SubSub1
        SubSub2
    Sub2
Cat2
    Sub1
Cat3
    Sub1
    Sub2
        SubSub1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [acts_as_tree](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree) plug-in

Answer (score 5):

Awesome_nested_set is the best solution, imo,  for these types of structures in rails.  http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

Comment: Agreed. It's nasty when it comes to writes, but when it comes to reads, it kicks ass. You can get the whole tree structure with one query.